# Can an interface specify only method names, but not return type?

Tags: c++, templates, interface, polymorphism

Suppose I have a class such as `Value` defined below.

```
template <typename T>
class Value : public ValueInterface
{
    public:
        // ...
        T getValue() const;

    private:
        T value_;
}
```

Can I refer to multiple `Value`s of different types (that is, with different `T` types) in my code generically (to create a container, for example)? My first thought was if it's possible to somehow declare a pure abstract class from which `Value` can inherit:

```
class ValueInterface
{
    public:
        ?? getValue() const = 0;
}

template <typename T>
class Value : public ValueInterface
{
    // ...
}

std::list<ValueInterface> lst;
Value<int> i(...);
Value<char> c(...);

lst.push_back(i);
lst.push_back(c);

int vi = i.getValue();
char vc = c.getValue();
```

If it is not possible, could you provide an alternate solution?

Comment: Can you give a pseudo-code example of how you'd like to use such a feature?

Comment: It's right there, in the second snippet. I need to declare a `std::list` to hold different `Value`s.

Comment: But what does that have to do with your `getValue` method?

Comment: I added some detail. Does this make any sense?

Comment: In your example, you aren't using the `getValue` method in a polymorphic way, so I'm not sure why you want to declare it `virtual`.  I also don't see what this has to do with the container.

Comment: I just realized that I'm trying to create a container of objects with different sizes, which I think is impossible.

Comment: Yes, that is one problem.  You can't store polymorphic objects in a container like this.  I still don't understand the issue with `getValue`, though!

Comment: You may find useful the `boost::any` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ all expressions must have a type known to the compiler, but in your solution `lst.begin()->getValue()` would not have any particular type.

Although if you look carefully to your example you are not calling `ValueInterface::getValue()` anywhere, just the subclasses versions.

You can try the following:

```
class ValueInterface
{
  public:
    template <typename T>
    T getValue() const
    {
        return dynamic_cast< const Value<T> &>(*this).getValue();
    }
    virtual ~ValueInterface()
    { }
};

template <typename T>
class Value : public ValueInterface
{
    public:
        // ...
        T getValue() const;

    private:
        T value_;
};
```

Note that `getValue()` is not (and cannot be) virtual.

Now you can write the code from your example, but also:

```
int z = lst.begin()->getValue<int>();
```

If you use the wrong type in the `getValue` call then an exception `std::bad_cast` will be thrown.

Comment: You need atleast one virtual function for `dynamic_cast` to work.

Comment: @Xeo Good point. The destructor is the best option here. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload on return type, as that would create all sorts of ambiguities.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here. I'm assuming you would iterate over `blah` or pick a random element from it, and then call `getValue()` on said element. This call could return absolutely any type: `char`, `const void*`, `Value< Value< Value<const void*> > >`, etc. What would you do with the result? How would you even define a variable for it?

Comment: A function using blah would know which elements returns what type, and would declare the variable accordingly.

Comment: @Dan: If you have compile time knowledge of the type of variable you're using, you don't need polymorphism in the first place.